# How to edit a variable that lives inside a matrix - Java?

Tags: java, matrix

I would like to change the variables value that are contained in the matrix.
Initialization value of the variables has to be zero, however for testing purpose c1 was initialized as an integer with value of 9 to see what would be reflected on the printing.
What I can see is that the initial value which the variable is the declared reflects properly when accessed from the matrix, however after attempting to increase the value, this only appears to be true only for the variable itself and not when accessed from the matrix.

```
package matrixvariable;


public class MatrixVariable {


    MatrixVariable(){             //Constructor

        getCajaUnoCount(); 
        getCajaDosCount(); 

        cajaUnoCountIncrement(); 
        cajaUnoCountIncrement();  

        getCajaUnoCount(); 
        getCajaDosCount();
        cajaTresCountIncrement(); 

        printContadores();
        sortContadoresCajas();
        System.out.println(contadoresCajas[0][0] + contadoresCajas[0][1]); //Manual checking

    }


    int c2,c3,tmp0,tmp1 = 0;
    int c1 =9;
    int [][] contadoresCajas= {{1,c1},{2,c2},{3,c3}};

     public void sortContadoresCajas(){

        System.out.println("OPS: sortContadoresCajas()");

        for(int i=0;i<=contadoresCajas.length-1;i++){
             for(int j=i;j<=contadoresCajas.length-1;j++){
                 if (contadoresCajas[j][1]<contadoresCajas[i][1]){
                     tmp0 = contadoresCajas[i][0];
                     tmp1 = contadoresCajas[i][1];

                     contadoresCajas[i][0]=contadoresCajas[j][0];
                     contadoresCajas[i][1]=contadoresCajas[j][1];
                     contadoresCajas[j][0]=tmp0;
                     contadoresCajas[j][1]=tmp1;
                }
            }
        }
        printContadores();
    }

    public void printContadores(){

        System.out.println("OPS : printContadores()");

        for(int i=0;i<=contadoresCajas.length-1;i++)       
            System.out.println("OPS : " +  contadoresCajas[i][0] + " " + contadoresCajas[i][1] );     
    }

    //PRINTERS

  public void getCajaUnoCount(){
        System.out.println("OPS : getCajaUnoCount()-> " + c1);     
    }

  public void getCajaDosCount(){
        System.out.println("OPS : getCajaDosCount()-> " + c2);   
    }

   public void getCajaTresCount(){
        System.out.println("OPS : getCajaTresCount()-> " + c3);     
    }



    public void cajaUnoCountIncrement(){
        System.out.println("OPS : cajaUnoCountIncrement()");
        c1++;
    }

    public void cajaDosCountIncrement(){
        System.out.println("OPS : cajaDosCountIncrement()");
        c2++;
    }

    public void cajaTresCountIncrement(){
        System.out.println("OPS : cajaTresCountIncrement()");
        c3++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixVariable foo = new MatrixVariable();
    }

}
```

All of this prints out the following:

```
run:
OPS : getCajaUnoCount()-> 9
OPS : getCajaDosCount()-> 0
OPS : cajaUnoCountIncrement()
OPS : cajaUnoCountIncrement()
OPS : getCajaUnoCount()-> 11
OPS : getCajaDosCount()-> 0
OPS : cajaTresCountIncrement()
OPS : printContadores()
OPS : 1 9   // 11?
OPS : 2 0
OPS : 3 0
OPS: sortContadoresCajas()
OPS : printContadores()
OPS : 2 0
OPS : 3 0
OPS : 1 9    //I would expect this to be 11
2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Your getters are not getters. The point of a getter is return a value, not to print it out and return nothing.

Comment: @khelwood removed comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the incremented values was not enough, I also had to tell it where to assign it, for this another function was created to assign it the required position:

```
public int findKey(int keytofind){
       System.out.println("OPS : keytofind is: " + keytofind);
       System.out.println("OPS : start :findKey()");

       for (int h=0; h<contadoresCajas.length;h++){

           if (contadoresCajas[h][0] == keytofind ){
               keyfound=h;
               System.out.println("OPS : keyfound is: " + keyfound);
            }

       }
       System.out.println("OPS : end :findKey()");
       return keyfound;
   }


    public void cajaUnoCountIncrement(){
        System.out.println("OPS : cajaUnoCountIncrement()");
        c1++;
        kf = findKey(1);
        contadoresCajas[kf][1] = c1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the incremented values to the matrix index you want to increment.

```
public void cajaUnoCountIncrement(){
    System.out.println("OPS : cajaUnoCountIncrement()");
    c1++;
    contadoresCajas[0][1] = c1;
}

public void cajaDosCountIncrement(){
    System.out.println("OPS : cajaDosCountIncrement()");
    c2++;
    contadoresCajas[1][1] = c2;
}

public void cajaTresCountIncrement(){
    System.out.println("OPS : cajaTresCountIncrement()");
    c3++;
    contadoresCajas[2][1] = c3;
}
```

> #### Output
>
> OPS : `getCajaUnoCount()-> 9`
>   OPS : `getCajaDosCount()-> 0`
>   OPS : `cajaUnoCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `cajaUnoCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `cajaDosCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `cajaDosCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `cajaDosCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `cajaTresCountIncrement()`
>   OPS : `getCajaUnoCount()-> 11`
>   OPS : `getCajaDosCount()-> 3`
>   OPS : `printContadores()`
>   OPS : `1 11`
>   OPS : `2 3`
>   OPS : `3 1`
>   OPS:  `sortContadoresCajas()`
>   OPS : `printContadores()`
>   OPS : `3 1`
>   OPS : `2 3`
>   OPS : `1 11`
>   4

Comment: That won't work because if I sort it out again with the sortContadoresCajas() it would return
```

OPS: sortContadoresCajas()
OPS : printContadores()
OPS : 3 1
OPS : 1 11
OPS : 2 12
```  which is wrong.

Comment: @DRP I cannot get how c2 will be 12 as you have never set c2 = c1

Comment: The idea is that I will never know before hand where c1,c2,or c3 will be sorted by the sortContadoresCajas(), hence I cannot predefine that c2 = c1 or any possible combination.

Comment: @DRP if you apply changes on the above fixes and tell a use case where it could break like the values of c1,c2 & c3

Comment: On the constructor if you add one more cajaUnoCountIncrement(); and sortContadoresCajas(); you will see the output mentioned in my first comment, which gives a wrong output because you would be incrementing the counter and assigning it to the incorrect spot. At this point I'm not sure what is the purpose of a use case. All that needs to happen is increment the variable and sort the keyvalue properly based on the value of the key. Our keys are 1, 2, 3, the variables are c1, c2, c3, therefore {1,c1} , {2,c2}, {3,c3}. So if c3 is lower than c2 & c1, then sort it to be first: {3,c3}, {2,c2},{1,c1}